# how to pass dynamic value in the array using donutchart in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

i am getting this response from back-end like this. how can i take this response in to state variable and how can i use the dynamic value to pass in this chart inside the data:[[ ]]array in reactjs. i am using in my code like this format. i need only dynamic value in this chart based on select the dropdown list select the one value(last day) and click on applying filter button. am sending the request and getting this (last day) response right. i need whatever value getting the response. i need to show dynamic value in this chats. based on applying the filter. how to do pass dynamic value in this data:[[]] array.

```
class Report extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            dashboardchart:{
                series:[{
                    data:[]
                }],

            },
        };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
        UserAction._getdashboardchart();
   }

    _userStoreChange(type, value) {
        if (type == 'DashboardChart') {
            let dashboardchart = UserStore._getdashboardchart() || {};
            this.setState({dashboardchart})
        }
    }

    render() {
        let chartdata = this.state.dashboardchart.series
        const piechart =  {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 45
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Claim - Key Performance Indicators'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    innerSize: 100,
                    depth: 45
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Total consumption',
                data: chartdata && chartdata.data && chartdata.data
            }]

          }

        return (
            <div className="panel-body">
                <ReactHighcharts config={piechart}></ReactHighcharts>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Report;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You pass the series array as a series.data. Could you prepare a working demo with this issue? You can use sample data with the same structure as yours. Check also this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r57245nw7. Do you use `highcharts-react` wrapper?

Comment: ok how can i pass the dynamic value for the same format in reactjs